# Unable to find wire from PSU for ATX_12_V_2

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I’m using following config

- Motherboard: Asus Prime Z590-P
- Power supply unit (PSU): be quiet pure power 11
- Processor: 10700k (Its unlocked although i’m not going to manually overclock but i think it requires more power than locked versions.  so maybe it matters )

As you see in the manual pictures I was able to find B and C on my PSU but can’t find what is A.

[image: Motherboard and PSU user manual]

UPDATE:
I looked around and realized not every PSU has 1x4 Motherboard Pin.  As most of the motherboard requires only 1x8 12V power pin. Although system will start with just the 1x8 too.

My CPU is an unlocked 10700k (125W TDP). Should I return my PSU and get another with both 1x8 12V and 1x4 12V connectors or use this PSU without 1x4 12v connection? Considering I’ll never manually overclock (don't even know how to.

Comment: The 8-pin ATX12V connector on your PSU can be split. // You wouldn’t normally connect both a 4-pin and an 8-pin ATX12V connector in parallel.

Comment: can be split?  not sure what that means. I mean i already connected the 8pin ATX_12_1 (shown as B in Mobo manual pictures) with my 4and 4 8pins 12v connector shown at top in my psu manual left page.  its just there’s nothing to connect to what shown as C in motherboard manual